# Where is a MutexGuard if I never assign it to a variable?

Tags: rust, mutex, mutability

I don't understand "where" the `MutexGuard` in the inner block of code is. The mutex is locked and unwrapped, yielding a `MutexGuard`. Somehow this code manages to dereference that `MutexGuard` and then mutably borrow that object. Where did the `MutexGuard` go? Also, confusingly, this dereference cannot be replaced with `deref_mut`. Why?

```
use std::sync::Mutex;

fn main() {
    let x = Mutex::new(Vec::new());
    {
        let y: &mut Vec<_> = &mut *x.lock().unwrap();
        y.push(3);
        println!("{:?}, {:?}", x, y);
    }

    let z = &mut *x.lock().unwrap();
    println!("{:?}, {:?}", x, z);
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Summary**: because `*x.lock().unwrap()` performs an [implicit borrow](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#implicit-borrows) of the operand `x.lock().unwrap()`, the operand is treated as a place context. But since our actual operand is not a place expression, but a value expression, **it gets assigned to an unnamed memory location (basically a hidden `let` binding)!**

See below for a more detailed explanation.

---

### Place expressions and value expressions

Before we dive in, first two important terms. Expressions in Rust are divided into two main categories: place expressions and value expressions.

- **Place expressions** represent a value that has a home (a memory location). For example, if you have `let x = 3;` then `x` is a place expression. Historically this was called *lvalue expression*.
- **Value expressions** represent a value that does not have a home (we can only use the value, there is no memory location associated with it). For example, if you have `fn bar() -> i32` then `bar()` is a value expression. Literals like `3.14` or `"hi"` are value expressions too. Historically these were called *rvalue expressions*.

There is a good rule of thumb to check if something is a place or value expression: "does it make sense to write it on the left side of an assignment?". If it does (like `my_variable = ...;`) it is a place expression, if it doesn't (like `3 = ...;`) it's a value expression.

There also exist *place contexts* and *value contexts*. These are basically the "slots" in which expressions can be placed. There are only a few *place contexts*, which (usually, see below) require a *place expression*:

- Left side of a (compound) assignment expression (`⟨place context⟩ = ...;`, `⟨place context⟩ += ...;`)
- Operand of an borrow expression (`&⟨place context⟩` and `&mut ⟨place context⟩`)
- ... plus a few more

Note that place expressions are strictly more "powerful". They can be used in a value context without a problem, because they *also* represent a value.

([relevant chapter in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions))

### Temporary lifetimes

Let's build a small dummy example to demonstrate a thing Rust does:

```
struct Foo(i32);

fn get_foo() -> Foo {
    Foo(0)
}

let x: &Foo = &get_foo();
```

This works!

We know that the expression `get_foo()` is a *value expression*. And we know that the operand of a borrow expression is a *place context*. So why does this compile? Didn't *place contexts* need *place expressions*?

Rust creates temporary `let` bindings! From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#temporary-lifetimes):

> When using a value expression in most place expression contexts, a temporary unnamed memory location is created initialized to that value and the expression evaluates to that location instead [...].

So the above code is equivalent to:

```
let _compiler_generated = get_foo();
let x: &Foo = &_compiler_generated;
```

This is what makes your `Mutex` example work: the `MutexLock` is assigned to a temporary unnamed memory location! That's where it lives. Let's see:

```
&mut *x.lock().unwrap();
```

The `x.lock().unwrap()` part is a value expression: it has the type `MutexLock` and is returned by a function (`unwrap()`) just like `get_foo()` above. Then there is only one last question left: is the operand of the deref `*` operator a place context? I didn't mention it in the list of place contests above...

### Implicit borrows

The last piece in the puzzle are implicit borrows. From [the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#implicit-borrows):

> Certain expressions will treat an expression as a place expression by implicitly borrowing it.

These include "the operand of the dereference operator (`*`)"! And all operands of any implicit borrow are place contexts!

So because `*x.lock().unwrap()` performs an implicit borrow, the operand `x.lock().unwrap()` is a place context, but since our actual operand is not a place, but a value expression, it gets assigned to an unnamed memory location!

### Why doesn't this work for `deref_mut()`

There is an important detail of "temporary lifetimes". Let's look at the quote again:

> When using a value expression in most place expression contexts, a temporary unnamed memory location is created initialized to that value and the expression evaluates to that location instead [...].

Depending on the situation, Rust chooses memory locations with different lifetimes! In the `&get_foo()` example above, the temporary unnamed memory location had a lifetime of the enclosing block. This is equivalent to the hidden `let` binding I showed above.

*However*, this "temporary unnamed memory location" is not always equivalent to a `let` binding! Let's take a look at this case:

```
fn takes_foo_ref(_: &Foo) {}

takes_foo_ref(&get_foo());
```

Here, the `Foo` value only lives for the duration of the `takes_foo_ref` call and not longer!

In general, if the reference to the temporary is used as an argument for a function call, the temporary lives only for that function call. This also includes the `&self` (and `&mut self`) parameter. So in `get_foo().deref_mut()`, the `Foo` object would also only live for the duration of `deref_mut()`. But since `deref_mut()` returns a reference to the `Foo` object, we would get a "does not live long enough" error.

That's of course also the case for `x.lock().unwrap().deref_mut()` -- that's why we get the error.

In the deref operator (`*`) case, the temporary lives for the enclosing block (equivalent to a `let` binding). I can only assume that this is a special case in the compiler: the compiler knows that a call to `deref()` or `deref_mut()` always returns a reference to the `self` receiver, so it wouldn't make sense to borrow the temporary for only the function call.

Comment: But here the lifetime of the temporary seems to be the enclosing block and not the innermost enclosing statement?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks for catching that! I was in a hurry and skipped over this important detail. I fixed my answer and now (almost) everything makes sense!

Answer (score 8):

Here are my thoughts:

```
let y: &mut Vec<_> = &mut *x.lock().unwrap();
```

A couple of things going on under the surface for your current code:

1. Your `.lock()` yields a `LockResult<MutexGuard<Vec>>`
2. You called `unwrap()` on the `LockResult` and get a `MutexGuard<Vec>`
3. Because `MutexGuard<T>` implements the `DerefMut` interface, Rust performs deref coercion. It gets dereferenced by the `*` operator, and yields a `&mut Vec`.

In Rust, I believe you don't call `deref_mut` by your own, rather [the complier will do the `Deref` coercion for you](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-02-deref.html#how-deref-coercion-interacts-with-mutability).

If you want to get your `MutexGuard`, you should not dereference it:

```
let mut y  = x.lock().unwrap();
(*y).push(3);
println!("{:?}, {:?}", x, y);
//Output: Mutex { data: <locked> }, MutexGuard { lock: Mutex { data: <locked> } }
```

From what I have seen online, people usually do make the `MutexGuard` explicit by saving it into a variable, and dereference it when it is being used, like my modified code above. I don't think there is an official pattern about this. Sometimes it will also save you from making a temporary variable.